# Rxweb validation not automatically setting fields as required? (Reactive forms validation)

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and I am using Rxweb reactive form validators to validate their inputs. More specifically, I have a password and a confirmPassword input. I want to be able to make the password input required if only it is not empty. I then want to make the confirmPassword required only if the password input is empty, and I also only want the confirmPassword to be valid if it matches the password input.

So far I have the following (all of which works, but not automatically...):

```
 password: ['', [
        RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.password !== "" }),
        Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}')
      ]],

      confirmPassword: ['', [
        RxwebValidators.required({ conditionalExpression: (x) => x.password !== "" }),
        RxwebValidators.compare({fieldName: 'password'}),
      ]]
      })
```

Everything above works fine, although if I add something to the password input, the confirmPassword input does NOT become valid until I click on it and start typing. My problem can be seen below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, there was an issue in the package, now it has been fixed in the latest [release (510 issue number)](https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb/releases/tag/v2.1.4).

please update the package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).